# how to make integer template argument accessible as templated class member?

Tags: c++, templates

A common pattern with templated classes is that template argument is typedef'ed inside the class to be easily accessible:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class T> struct Foo{
    typedef T type;
};
static_assert(std::is_same<Foo<int>::type,int>::value,"");
```

How can I do the same with non-type template argument? I only had the following idea, but there gotta be something more elegant?

```
template<int I> struct Bar{
   constexpr static int getI(){ return I; }
};
static_assert(Bar<5>::getI()==5,"error");
```

Comment: Why is that not elegant?

Comment: it is a method call; why is that a problem?

Comment: It is not a "normal" method call but a `constexpr`, an expression resolved at compile-time. For that reason I prefer to it to look differently if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might use an `enum`, but the utility of this seems somewhat limited to me...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int N> struct Foo
{
    enum {value_ = N};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{            
    Foo<42> foo;

    cout << foo.value_;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit to include that this kind of thing is frequently done in template metaprogramming.

Comment: Cool! Exactly what I needed. It can be quite useful if the template is passed as argument to another function, which might want to query that parameter; unless it is "saved" somewhere in this way, it is not accessible.

Comment: Consider e.g. [std::tuple_size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size). I think it is highly inelegant. `std::tuple<...>::size` would be much more readable.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a static const variable:

```
template<int I> struct Bar{
    static const int i = I;
};

static_assert(Bar<5>::i==5,"error");
```

Comment: You'd have to remember to define it somewhere though, which is annoying.

Comment: Right, for that reason I did not propose that. It compiles file and then I get error at link-time.